# When trying to run folder with "npm run dev" and getting "node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1050"

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to run a folder using  `npm run dev` and I keep getting the same error.

```
PS C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\My Folder> npm run dev
Debugger attached.

> elagant-music-app@0.0.0 dev
> vite

'Folder\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1050
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\vite\bin\vite.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:893:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.14.0
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I am running the folder from this YT video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1cpb0tYV74
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iTlXIZ4T3BBKjgLMsDpQn-Eux1B3ZyXO/view

I am looking to get a localhost link to start coding.

How do I fix this?

I have tried restarting VS Code and running `npm run dev` several times to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete your node_modules and package-lock.json files, but not package.json and then run in terminal this command to install dependencies again: 'npm install', wait to install and after that restart your editor.
Hope this help.